# how to apply multiple SSL certificates to multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, ssl

I have one web application in which I have two external sites :

1. Mydomain.co.uk -internet zone
2. mydomain.com-intranet zone

And I have two certificates available with me which I purchased for this two external website :

1. Mydomain.co.uk
2. Mydomain.com

**Problem :**

I can only able to apply one certificate on port 443(Mydomain.co.uk).

Both the sites (Mydomain.co.uk, mydomain.com) are fetching the certificate which is applied on 443 ports (https).

Therefore only one site is working fine (the certificate which is assign to port 443, only that site will work).

So initially I have applied **mydomain.co.uk** certificate on **443** then mydomain.co.uk site is working fine and **mydomain.com** is having a Certificate error (it is pointing to mydomain.co.uk certificate.)

These certificates issued by **Certificate Authority**.

I have also tried by creating an extended web application but no success.

*Note* : I have a single IP address.

Comment: Please refer to this related post and its answers : http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/63199/17814

Comment: thanks for the reply.i am facing a different issue.1.this certificates are not wildcard certi. and 2.i am having iis 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a wildcard certificate as you have two different domain names. Instead, you need to use a SAN (also called UCC) certificate which can have multiple domain names attached to it. I'm not endorsing this vendor, but take a look at http://www.thawte.com/ssl/san-uc-ssl-certificates/index.html as an example of what you need to purchase.

Comment: Oops, good point for the wildcard and 2 domains, my bad. But he could have use intranet.dom and extranet.dom or w/e.

Comment: The other option is to use SNI, but only if the OP is running on Server 2012 R2.

Comment: Thanks,If Sites are like mydomain.com and mysite.co.uk which certificate is required .

Comment: A SAN certificate.

Comment: if i want to use both the sites parallelly then SAN certificate is usefull for IIS 7?whether multiple ip addresses are required to browse the sites parallally.(You will also see that only one of the Websites will be running. Other Websites will be in stopped state because we cannot have multiple Websites running with same IP and same SSL port binding. )http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varunm/archive/2013/06/18/bind-multiple-sites-on-same-ip-address-and-port-in-ssl.aspx

Comment: No, you must have both bindings on the same IIS Site with IIS7 and a SAN cert. If you use IIS 8 (Server 2012) you can have multiple SSL bindings per IP address via SNI.

Answer (score 1):

According to the post I linked in my above comment, and [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/9ef1dc30-4e41-4ca0-bfea-4b3060ccc7b5/multiple-web-applications-using-ssl-on-one-ip?forum=sharepointadmin) one.

Wildcard can be a solution to use SSL for multiples IIS sites.

But as you bought 2 certificates, I would advice you to create/use another IP, or use host header, depending of your IIS Versions.

Comment: we are not able to provide host header as it is disabled for https binding in IIS7.wheather there is any alternative solution other than multiple ip address.